# How to convert courses and hours (from a non-european university) to ECTS?

Tags: undergraduate, degree, europe

I'm getting my "Licentiate of Computers/Systems" degree soon, in Argentina.
The degree is composed by 40 courses of 68 hours of lectures each. On top of that, you have to add the time you spend on assignments, studying for exams, etc. Depending on the course, you might have to spend from 30 hours to 250, but of course, this depends on each person.
You are supposed to take 5 courses per semester if you want to get the degree in 4 years (full-time).

I don't know how to convert my degree credits/hours into ECTS, given that, if I understood correctly, ECTS points do include studying and assignments hours.

I'd appreciate if someone could enlighten me. Please, let me know if more information is needed in order to calculate the ECTS.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting a degree in Argentina, then you should be concerned about the eligibility/mapping of the actual degree, not on the ECTS of individual courses.

ECTS of individual courses would apply if you want to get a degree in EU but have some of your earlier courses of an unfinished degree to count towards that new degree;  However, if you want to continue studies in, say, a masters programme then you'd enroll based on your Licentiate degree as whole, and none of the courses would be spearately treated.

In any case, if you need 'proper ECTS conversion', then you'll most likely need an official statement about that from the institution giving you the degree, not anyone else.

Comment: In my case, I want to get the Licentiate degree and then go for a Master's in EU.
I thought I could get my ECTS based on the amount of courses and hours I had to take. I'll wait for some more answers before choosing this as correct, so I can see what other people think. But this is useful. Thank you!